# Reading and interpreting output sensitivity of a load cell from data sheet

Tags: maximum-ratings, load-cell, sensitivity

I'm given these ratings /spec for load cell / sensor:

- Range: 0-200kg
- ***Output sensitivity: 0.7 ± 0.15mV / V***
- Nonlinear: 0.05% F.S
- Hysteresis: 0.05% F.S
- Repeatability: 0.05% F.S
- Creep: 0.05% F.S/3min
- Zero output: ±0.1mV/V
- Input impedance: 1050±10Ω/1050±10Ω (self-compensation) Output
  impedance: 1050 ± 10Ω
- Operating temperature: -10~+45°C
- Wiring method: red (power positive), black (power negative), green
  (signal positive), white (signal negative)
- Zero temperature drift: 0.05% F.S/10°C
- Temperature sensitivity drift: 0.05% F.S/10°C
- Insulation resistance: ≥2000MΩ
- Excitation voltage: 3~10VDC
- Overload capability: 150% F.S
- Four-corner error: ±0.05% F.S

I know this is likely dumb question, but is the sensitivity there 0.7V +/- 0.15mV, or is this 0.7mV +/- ..? Probably 700mV/V is too much, but 0.7mV/V sounds too little .. ? (or does it..)

If 0.7mV/V, if I'm applying 5V input - that's my plan - this will be output range 0 - 3.5mV, which seems too low ?

Comment: From the information that you provide, the only conclusive answer that can be given is that; The output sensitivity is 0.7 [NO UNIT] +- (0.15 mV/V).. So the output sensitivity here has no unit, but it varies with 0.15mV pr. V, That seems strange. I would bet that there is some more information in the datasheet which when put together with this makes everything make sense. I think that the output sensitivity is relative to the supply voltage, so you probably can't just equate 0.7 to 700mV or 0.7mV, it probably depends on your supply voltage.

Comment: Hey @Vinzent, don't have datasheet but supplier (seller) just has description as i c&p above. The item is as here : [link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/200kg-Electronic-Platform-Scale-Aluminium-Alloy-Weighing-Sensor-Load-Cell-Weight/323878784765?epid=0&hash=item4b68ae0efd:g:HAMAAOSwQ8xdSpMs)

Answer (score 1):

I think that what they mean by "Output Sensitivity" is what is also sometimes referred to as the "Full-Scale Deflection", and the reason that they are not giving it a unit is because it is relative to the supply voltage, or here "Excitation Voltage", which they require to be between 3V and 10V.

So in other words, this is how I would calculate the parameters I need to use this sensor;

First we choose a supply voltage between 3V and 10V, lets use 3V for this example.

Vcc = 3v

Now we calculate the Full-Scale Deflection voltage, ie. the voltage out of the sensor when the sensor is under full load.

Vfsd = Vcc * 0.7 = 2.1V

Now we look at the range of the sensor which is 0-200kg, from this I would assume that Vfsd corrosponds to 200kg of load on the sensor, so to calculate the output voltage (Vo) pr. kg of load on the sensor we simply divide;

Vo = Vfsd / 200kg = 2.1V / 200kg = 10.5 mV/kg

To this we have to add an error of +- 0.15 mV/V, so at the full scale deflection the error will be;

Vfsd * 0.15mV/V = 2.1V * 0.15mV/V = 0.315mV

Comment: Oh i see. So if I want to use 5V, then that's  Vfsd = 3.5V,  or Vo = 17.5mV/kg.

Comment: Btw, about Output Sensitivity. This is how Sensitivity explained in relation to load cell (for weighting scale) :  _"The sensitivity of a load cell is defined as full load output voltage in relation to the excitation voltage. It is generally expressed in mV/V. This value corresponds to the voltage deviation caused by the load cell at full load when excited by a 1V source. The sensitivity of load cells is very low (generally about 2mV/V). If a system has a 3.3V excitation voltage then at full load, the output voltage will be 6.6mV"_  (source: EE times, weighting scale design)

Comment: sorry but I looked more at how they generally specify these load cells, and I think, apologies for this, your interpretation is not / shouldn't be right. See here for example : [link](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/20140804160582898289.jpg).   Thus I think it should be 0.7mV/V +/- error for my bar.